# using selectors in jquery ui / autocomplete / source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="name">
First: <input type="text" name="firstName" class="firstName">
Last: <input type="text" name="lastName" class="lastName">
</div>
```

Here's the JS that corresponds to that HTML:

```
$('.lastName').last().autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    var firstName = $('.firstName', $(this).closest('.name'));
    var lastName = request.term;
    console.log(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
  }
});
```

I'd like to have autocomplete pull the closest `.firstName` to the `.lastName` field that the source method is linked to but it's not working.

Superficially it seems like if that's not gonna work that I could attach some sort of unique ID to `.lastName` but if the only thing I can access is `request` then it's not like I can simply add a `data-whatever` attribute to the `<input>` element.

Any ideas?

Here's my JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f86nLrq9/

Comment: Really not clear how you expect this to work. Typically you have an array of choices to select from. That array would be passed to `response(array)` in the `source` callback. What would you use the first name for while trying to select last name?

Comment: FYI to get the value from the adjacent firstname would be `$(this).siblings('.firstname').val()`

Comment: The `this` is ambiguous. You must use a more specific selector.

Comment: Looking into this further, use `$(this.element)` for proper reference. `this` is in relationship to the Instance and not the Element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/39mrzowc/39/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.lastName:last').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var fName = $(this.element).prev().val();
      console.log(fName, request.term);
      response([]);
    },
  });
});
```

If you examine `this`, you will see it is a reference to the Autcomplete Instance (a data Object). Most of the Widgets have a reference to the Element, see: https://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/

That means that `this`, was not a reference to the element `input.lastName`; hence, the code you were using was not working. Your same code with this minor change will work too: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/yucabv8m/1/

**JavaScript**

```
$('.lastName').last().autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    var firstName = $('.firstName', $(this.element).closest('.name')).val();
    var lastName = request.term;
    console.log(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
  }
});
```